# Getting info from HTML set in a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
function (foo) {

}
```

Foo contains some HTML. For example:

```
<div>
    <div>
      <div class="myclass>
        <div> 
          Hello World
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract that info off the variable somehow.

I have tried:

```
function (foo) {
    $('.myclass > script').text()
}
```

I probably need some way to select foo instead. Any help?

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to ask here. What non-existing `script` element that is a child of `.myclass` are you trying to select here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in jQuery then you need to convert the string of HTML held in `foo` in to a jQuery object which you can interrogate with jQuery methods to retrieve the data you need. For example:

```js
function getText(foo) {
  return $(foo).find('.myclass').text();
}

let input = '<div><div><div class="myclass"><div> Hello World</div></div></div></div>';
console.log(getText(input));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```